How can I run MSCs, such as services.msc, as System||TrustedInstaller?
I want to run the Services MMC [services.msc] / other MMCs as System||TrustedInstaller and have tried using NirSoft's AdvancedRun, but it only works for .exe files.
Is there a way to do this in Windows 10?

[Edit] your question to indicate which service precisely your trying to disable

I managed to get around the problem by disabling the service using MS Autoruns.

@Ramhound I edited the post. The solution I'm seeking isn't just to disable a single service, but I want to know generally if there is a way to run *.msc files as SYSTEM / TrustedInstaller.

If you provide the service name there might be a way to disable the service you have thought of, but I can’t research those possibilities, if you don’t mention the name of the service

The application that opens/shows .msc files is Microsoft Management Console, mmc.exe.

What practical use case is there for running services.msc as System or TrustedInstaller (latter of which has system permissions higher than System and is intended only for installing of trusted software from Microsoft, such as Windows Updates)? There is no use case AFAIK, as all services can be stopped/disabled from it, and if not, simply launching it from an Admin terminal should resolve that. SysInternals PsExec can launch executables as System.

@JW0914
"What practical use case is there for running services.msc as System or TrustedInstaller?"
I don't know yet. It's simply a question of "Can I do this?". Even if I don't have a use case yet, I still want to know if it's possible. For instance, running regedit as SYSTEM can help with editing or deleting keys that are normally protected when running as Admin/User. Why do I need to provide a use case to ask this question?

I figured it out, thanks to @DanielB. Using NirSoft's AdvancedRun, you run "C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe" and specify a command line argument of the *.msc file you want to open. I.E services.msc, or devmgmt.msc, etc.
Thanks @DanielB for the tip.

@fmotion1 ...we appreciate the update, but within the Super User realm we don't add answers that are found within the question itself.  Please submit your own separate answer, instead.

@fmotion1 Simply because you can run an executable or service as System||TrustedInstaller doesn't mean you should - executables should be launched with the least amount of permissions required to do what needs to be done, and since all services can be managed with Admin permissions, why would System||TrustedInstaller-level permissions ever be required? As to RegEdit, it doesn't need to be launched as System to change even a key that is owned by TrustedInstaller - it's massive overkill and carries the risk of accidentally crippling the OS by doing something that can't be undone.

@JW0914 I appreciate your words of caution. I am not going to cripple my OS. I have used windows for most of my life and I understand the risks and possible ramifications of running an application at high elevation levels. At any rate, I agree with you here: "Executables should be launched with the least amount of permissions required to do what needs to be done". And that's what I normally do. Thanks for the concern.

I figured it out, thanks to Daniel B. Using NirSoft's AdvancedRun, you point the application to run C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe and specify a command line argument of the *.msc file you want to open.

For example: services.msc, devmgmt.msc, gpedit.msc, diskmgmt.msc, etc. Thanks @DanielB for the nudge in the right direction.
You can verify with ProcessHacker to view elevation status, and it indeed shows NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for mmc.exe:

I also tried David Shader's approach with psexec.exe / psexec64.exe, but couldn't get it to work:
psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe -nobanner -accepteula fails and returns:
Error creating key file on DESKTOP-CD0OK73:
The network path was not found.


Another good way is to use psexec:
psexec.exe -i -s <LOCAL COMMAND, ex - CMD>
Doesn't work remotely though, afaik

Has the man page been reviewed?
